# Scarlett 8i6 Line In to Windows audio

Tags: mixer, windows, troubleshooting, sound-card

Does anyone know if there's a way to take the line in from my Scarlett 8i6 sound card and pipe it to my windows audio?  (In addition to using the usb connection and hearing it through my monitors)

I bought x2 6.8mm to x1 3.5mm converter but I can't get windows to hear line in.  I can connect 1 mono cable to a powered amp and hear audio from the card but for whatever reason my os doesn't detect anything is coming through the 3.5mm jack (despite the fact my outputs are clearly working).

Anyone got any ideas on this?  I figured this would be pretty doable but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to plug the output of your scarlett to your windows line-in but a focusrite Scarlett 8i6 is an audio interface that means it can replace your windows built-in sound card altogether.

Hopefully you installed the drivers needed. Your signal chain should be Mic/Instrument --XLR/PL--> Scarlett 8i6 --USB--> Computer

Then you should choose/set your recording/playback devices on your computer to Scarlett device (right click the volume icon on the lower right and select recording/playback devices)